# Vanilla JS ForEach element and assigning ascending variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple one month calendar using Vanilla JS. I read that PHP can be used to create multiple repeating elements but I was wondering whether doing it the I'm trying is possible. I'm creating buttons and using a for loop to make 31 of them to fill up my month. I'm also trying to make it so the button contains the day number using the variable `day`. Not sure how to do that, I was thinking for loop and using `i` as the value for `day`, but then it would just end on whatever the last `i` value was.

Since it's not working I'm coming here for help, I'd like to solve this using Vanilla JS if possible. Thank you.

TLDR: For loop to make buttons and variable to assign ascending value to each.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var day;

        function dateMaker() {
            for (i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
                var btn = document.createElement("button");
                btn.className("date");
                btn.innerHTML = day;
                document.body.appendChild(btn);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>July 2020</h1>
    <div id="calendar">
        <script>
            dateMaker();
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `btn.classList.add` fix that too - `day` will be undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add use `classList.add` to add class to your dynamic elements. Couple of mistakes and fixes which i have hightlighted below

1. Also, ideally use [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) intead of `.innerHTML`
2. You can appendChild and display you days in the calendar
3. Use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add classes to your dynamic elements
4. You are declaring `day` variable but not using it in your code.

Run Snippet below.

```js
function dateMaker() {
  for (i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.classList.add("date");
    btn.textContent = i;
    document.getElementById('calendar').appendChild(btn) ;
  }
}
dateMaker();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var day;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>July 2020</h1>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
    <script>
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```